# Estimate for matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, analysis, determinant, interpolation

Can anybody help me with this? Is the following statement true? Can anybody prove it (or prove it wrong)?

For $m<n$ let $\mathcal{M}:=\{A=(v_1,\ldots,v_m)\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}:\; <v_i,v_j>=\delta_{ij} \;\forall i,j\}$.

Moreover, let $\mathcal{A}\subset \mathcal{M}$ be a set with the property $\det(A^tB)>0 \; \forall A,B\in \mathcal{A}$.

Then there exists a $\theta=\theta(n)>0$ and a $C\in \mathcal{M}$ such that $\det(A^tC)>\theta \; \forall A\in \mathcal{A}$.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: You are likely to get better help if you specify exactly what part you are stuck at.

Comment: I really don't know how to begin with this exercise because I don't know how the set of matrices "looks like" - I only know the property that is satisfied. This makes things difficult for me.

Comment: It is a bit tricky to see what's going on. Let's try small values for the parameters. Say, $m=1, n=2$. In that case we have $A=A(\theta)=(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$ for some $\theta$. Furthermore, in this case $\det(A(\alpha)^t A(\beta))=\cos(\alpha-\beta)$. This places restrictions on the range of choices for $\theta$ such that $A(\theta)\in\mathcal{A}$. I'm sure you can take this special case from here.

Comment: The reason for making that comment was that somebody suggested this question should be closed for lack of context. They have a point (even though I voted against closing). If you add a solution to the $n=2,m=1$ case I think we can more or less guarantee that the question won't attract too much such negative attention. Really, I think this is a fine question, and together with eventual answers will add useful content to the site (unless we locate a dupe). I don't know about the general case (other than $m=n$, which seems easy).

Comment: Another way of thwarting attempts to close this would be to explain, where you encountered this question. It doesn't look like homework to me, but what do I know :-)

Comment: I refer most new users to [our local guide for askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/11619).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the asker has apparently abandoned the question. It was borderline in the context department to begin with :-(